# How to Enter multiple items in an array to another array at a specific index?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array

```
array1 = [1,2,3,6,7,8]

array2 = [40,50]
```

How can i push items in array2 to array1 to get a result

```
 result = [1,2,3,40,50,6,7,8];
```

keep in mind its not a simple concatination, need to insert the scecond array in specific index.

```
array1.splice(3, 0, array1 ); => splice doesnt accept another array.
```

How can i enter items in diffrent array to a specific index?

Im trying this in angular

```
array1 .splice(3, 0,...array2);
```

and getting the im getting spread array doesn't support in tslib

Comment: `array1.splice(3, 0, ...array2);` will do the job, although this will **alter** `array1`, so I'm assuming you want `array1` to be `result`. Of course, I also assume that your environment supports the spread operator.

Comment: Following @briosheje's comment, I suggest you read about spread operators in general - they were introduced exactly to aid for these cases: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: Do you want to alter `array1` or do you want to create a new array that is the result of the concatenation?

Comment: the im getting spread array doesn't support in tslib

Answer (score 1):

```js
var array1 = [1,2,3,6,7,8]

var array2 = [40,50]


function cobmine(arr1,arr2,index){
  var arr3=arr1.splice(0,index);
  var arr4=arr1.splice(-index);
  return arr3.concat(arr2).concat(arr4)
}

var result=cobmine(array1,array2,3);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your env does not support spread syntax for some reason you could stick to ES5 `apply` technique.

```js
array1 = [1,2,3,6,7,8]

array2 = [40,50]

array1.splice.apply(array1, [3, 0].concat(array2))

console.log(JSON.stringify(array1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to add array at a specific index

```
const arr1 = [1,2,3,6,7,8]
const arr2 = [40,50]
const index = 3

const newArr = [
    ...arr1.slice(0, index),
    ...arr2,
    ...arr1.slice(index + 1),
]
// [1,2,3,40,50,6,7,8]
```